# Where is the fuse located for the backup light in a 2002 BMW 530i

Tags: electrical

I have no reverse lights just trying to check the fuse

Comment: https://fuse-box.info/bmw/bmw-5-series-f10-f11-f07-f18-2011-2017-fuses-and-relay/amp

Comment: There is no backup light fuse, these lights are controlled by the Light Module which is fuse #16.